# Getting data from specific multiple columns

Tags: excel

Below is all the value that has been given. However, I would like to extract the values from the each row such as  C,F,I,L columns and so on.  BTW , it may be different columns for each rows like below. not matter how many columns.

and below is the result that I would like to have.

[image]

Comment: Why don't you select all data and create a pivot table that way you can select whatever data you want.

Comment: The only way is if there is a pattern, every 3rd column, all start with `host` otherwise how is excel supposed to know which to return?

Comment: @ScottCraner yes like you said it would be every 3rd column as pattern such as C,F,I,L columns and so on   , btw not starting with `host`.  I wrote them as sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A6:INDEX(6:6,MATCH("zzz",6:6)),,INT((COLUMN(A1)-1)*3)+3),"")
```

It will return the value in every third column as it is copied across.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I am getting an error message : There is a problem with this formula. To get around this , type an apostrophe (') first

Comment: @Arbelac do you use `;` instead of `,` in your formula?

Comment: ok my last question is : how can I set A1 instead of  A6 cell ?

Comment: Change all the `6` to `1` there are 5